# How to choose a specified profile to scan code

Tags: java, sonarqube

SonarQube:
Community Edition
Version 8.7.1 (build 42226
SonarScanner :4.7.0.2747
INFO: Java 11.0.14.1 Eclipse Adoptium (64-bit)
INFO: Windows 11 10.0 amd64

when i run `sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectKey=java-checkstyle -Dsonar.host.url=http://124.223.25.135:9000/ -Dsoner.profile=Checkstyle` , i choose a specified profile "Checkstyle " and it logs :

```
INFO: Load project settings for component key: 'java-checkstyle'
INFO: Load project settings for component key: 'java-checkstyle' (done) | time=434ms
INFO: Load quality profiles
INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=477ms
INFO: Load active rules
INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=8133ms
INFO: Indexing files...
INFO: Project configuration:
INFO: Load project repositories
INFO: Load project repositories (done) | time=477ms
INFO: 127 files indexed
INFO: 113 files ignored because of scm ignore settings
INFO: Quality profile for css: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for java: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for js: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for xml: Sonar way
```

but it does not work, it run default profile "Sonar way", I want to run my profile “Checkstyle”, I already set a profile named “Checkstyle” in SonarQube,

[image]

I need to run many profiles to check my code such as profile-1,profile-2 , but i don’t know how to set when I run scanner, do you have any way to help

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/8.7/analysis/analysis-parameters/) there are no parameter to specify the quality profile through the scanner. You can only scan against one quality profile and that must be set in the UI or through REST API.

The problem with having multiple quality profiles will be there might be conflict between rules like one profile may classify a rule as major and another might classify the same rule as info.